# Check if user like the facebook post or not with graph API

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-feed

I'm not getting any leads how to check whether user has like the feed or not.
I'm displaying all the feeds of my page and I want to know whether user has liked the feed or not.
One solution is get all the likes and search for our id, that is not a good approach.

[image: Tried this way, but it's not working]

Comment: check out my answer. may i ask why you need the information? it would be easier to help if we know the specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

`/me/likes` is for getting the liked Facebook Pages only, and you need the `user_likes` permission for that. Afaik there is no way to check if a user likes a specific post, you could only access the post with the API and go through the likes (`/post-id`) - but you would not be able to match the IDs to the authorized user (global !== app scoped id).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. In our app we have integrated our Facebook page feeds, so we list the feeds exactly like the FB feeds in iOS/Android app. In that we have given the features to: "Like the post",  "Comment on post" and "Share the post". So, if user has already liked the post, it should display as Liked.

Comment: Link how we show the feeds:[List Feeds](https://postimg.org/image/neuxy0nft/) 
The FQL code which used to work before: [FQL Query Code](https://postimg.org/image/t8stab5in/)

Comment: try getting the likes with /post-id/likes - but i am pretty sure you will not get app scoped ids - so, as i said in my answer, you can´t match the ids.

Comment: You are right, I can get a solution of this from getting all the likes and then check my id if it's there or not. But, I don't think that's a good approach..

Comment: it´s the only approach afaik - and again, i don´t think it will work, because of the app scoped ids ;)